# printing random list with the possibility of repeating items in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, random

If I have a list of 10 items like `["item1", "item2", "item3", ..., "item10"]`

```
random.sample(range(10), 4)
```

would return a list of 4 **unique** items within the range.

Is there another "random" method that returns a random list with the possibility of repeating items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a *trivial* function (like `sample`) for sampling with replacement because it's *so* trivial you really don't need one:

```
[random.choice(range(10)) for _ in range(4)]
```

There *is* a function for less-trivial uses of sampling with replacement, [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices). And you can call it with no weights or anything else if you want:

```
random.choices(range(10), k=4)
```

But it's not really any easier to understand.

Comment: There is [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) nowadays :)

Comment: @miradulo I was editing that into th question, trying to figure out how to should explain that it adds a 3.6 dependency that you probably don't need and requires using a keyword argument, and then decided to strip all of that out…

Comment: Sure, to each their own I suppose - I find it trivial enough.

Comment: Thank you this code: [random.choice(range(10)) for _ in range(4)] did the job. I have python 2.7, so random.choices wouldn't work

Comment: @miradulo Looks like the 3.6 dependency turned out to be relevant after all. (It's always hard to guess with minimalist questions…)